# Create 1 banner for each activity or can I use the same?

Tags: admob, banner

In AdMob, I need to create 1 banner for each activity or can I use the same?

Act1:
- Banner 1 (with ID: 1234).
Act2:
- Banner 1 (with ID: 1234).

OR

Act1:
- Banner 1 (with ID: 1234).
Act2:
- Banner 2 (with ID: 4321).

What is correct or better?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not destroying the Ad in your Activity onDestroy callback method which may make issues. So better destroy Ads on each activity once activity is destroyed. You can use the same Ad Id for multiple activities. No problem for that. But keep in mind about destroying each Ads once activity is closed, So if you are using the same Ad for multiple activities, declare separately in each activities. Hope its clear.

Comment: My XML code example:
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adViewMain"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

Comment: If I have only one Ad in all app, always using destroy(); It's better than use multiples Ads always using destroy();??

Comment: No I think you can use the same Ad but reusing it in every activity by killing it on every activity's destroy() ..